# Excel copy adjacent values of a selected column with no entries in the cells

Tags: vba, excel

```
A      B      C        D

1     ...     1        2

2     ...    1.2       

3     ...    1.9

4     ...    1.1       4

5     ...     1        3

6     ...     1

7     ...     1        5

8     ...     3
```

The function I need should search through col D and find all rows with no entries and then copy the corresponding values from col A and col B to another sheet.

For example in this dummy code, A2,A3,A6,A8 and B2,B3,B6,B8 have to copied to a new sheet.

I tried using vlookup and index command but it only gets the value of the first entries and dragging it down doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do what you want, simply change the Sheet numbers to reflect the Sheets you are using (I am using Sheet1 as the sheet with the data and Sheet3 to where the summary data should be placed) these Sheet names are their coded version and not their name on the bottom tab on excel:

```
Sub foo()
LastRow = Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'change Sheet1 to your sheet ie. Sheets("Sheet1")
For i = 2 To LastRow
    If Sheet1.Cells(i, 4).Value = "" Then
        NextEmptyRow = Sheet3.Cells(Sheet3.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        Sheet3.Cells(NextEmptyRow, 1).Value = Sheet1.Cells(i, 1).Value
        Sheet3.Cells(NextEmptyRow, 2).Value = Sheet1.Cells(i, 2).Value
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

**UPDATE:**

If you are referring to the Sheets by their name in the bottom tab of excel then you should change the code above for this one:

```
Sub foo()
Dim ws1 As Worksheet: Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet1") 'change the name of your sheets here
Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = Sheets("Sheet3")
LastRow = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 
For i = 2 To LastRow
    If ws1.Cells(i, 4).Value = "" Then
        NextEmptyRow = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        ws2.Cells(NextEmptyRow, 1).Value = ws1.Cells(i, 1).Value
        ws2.Cells(NextEmptyRow, 2).Value = ws1.Cells(i, 2).Value
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: I get a run-time error in line 5 with the message object required. I'm new to this.

Comment: The error you are getting is because you probably don't have a Sheet3 in your spreadsheet, so changing the names to the actual ones you have in your spreadsheet will make it so that the code works as expected.

Comment: The data is in sheet 1 and the summary should go to sheet 3 which I created as per your code.

Comment: I've updated my answer, just make sure you add the space between Sheet and the number 1 if that's how your sheet is named when looking at the tabs on the bottom of your excel file. The same with Sheet3 if it is Sheet 3.

Comment: might be simpler if you make the worksheets as dims, ie `dim ws1 as worksheet: ws1 = Sheets("sheet name")` so that they don't have to replace it everywhere

Comment: Thank you so much! It helped a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is using filter on column D provided you set your data up with a filter.

```
Sub CopyData()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wsSource As Worksheet
    Dim wsTarget As Worksheet

   Set wb = ThisWorkbook
   Set wsSource = wb.Worksheets("Source") ' change as appropriate
   Set wsTarget = wb.Worksheets("Target") ' change as appropriate

        With wsSource
            .ListObjects("Table1").AutoFilter.ShowAllData
            .ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="="
            .AutoFilter.Range.Columns("A:B").Copy wsTarget.Range("A1")
       End With
End Sub
```